# Is there a way to create a vertical carousel in Google's Materialize CSS without having to build it custom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am looking to have a vertical scrolling "carousel" using Google's Materialize CSS library, I understand the steps to build a carousel

```
# haml
%ul.carousel
  %li.carousel-item
     Some Content
  %li.carousel-item
     Some other Content
  ...

$(document).ready(function(){
  %('.carousel').carousel({
    some: 'option',
  })
})
```

Is there some option that could be passed either in the HTML or js that would allow for a vertical scroll to be achieved?

From what I see the js adds the class '.scrolling' to the '.carousel' when the animation starts which add the styles

```
.carousel.scrolling{style="z-index: 0; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; 
  transform: translateX(0px) translateX(5.64957px) translateX(0px) 
  translateZ(0px);"}
```

Is there a way to override the translateX to a translateY?
I have also tried to add styles such as

```
.carousel{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: As far i know there is no such way to create vertical scrolling , try using flexsilder.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like a simple way to do this, but since no one commented on any answer, thinking of a simple solution that will suit many cases, you can simply rotate the carousel using css transform, and then rotate back item by item. Not tested yet, but it should work.